# How can I optimize performance of an EF Code First desktop app with mostly read-only tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Facts:**

- I have a desktop app backed by a SQL CE database.
- Many of the tables are read-only.
- I'm using EF Code First to generate the database and handle crud operations.
- I generally keep one DbContext open for the whole session and dispose on app exit. (Note: I've tried creating a new DbContext more frequently and found that performance was actually worse. Also, I don't ever need to roll back changes.)
- For several of my entities, I have added some getters to provide necessary data derived from other properties of the entity. A few of these getters actually perform LINQ queries (which I suspect is part of my problem).

Everything is working, but I'm realizing now that I need to do some optimization. Performance is somewhat sluggish in general, but I'm especially concerned about one really giant query users need to run periodically that flattens pretty much the whole database into a single table then outputs it to a delimited text file. This query is taking much longer than I'd like.

One idea I have for speeding things up would be to store anything that is read-only in a `List` instead of grabbing it from my DbContext each time I need it. The tricky part is that, while I could easily grab all my `Car` entities from the DbContext and store them in a list, how would I ensure that all the "helper properties", such as `public virtual ICollection<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }` or `public virtual Engine Engine { get; set; }` get stored as well? It doesn't do a lot of good to iterate through all the `Car` entities if all the associated entities are not iterated as well.

The other idea I have for improving performance is to come up with a way to cache the getters that are the most processor intensive. As I mentioned above, some of my getters actually perform LINQ queries. I know this is sapping performance, but since some of these are dependent on data that can change, caching becomes quite tricky. I have a feeling it would require implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

What I'd like is a strategy for improving performance without throwing away all the good things that EF is already doing for me. There's no point in me storing something in a list, for example, if EF has already iterated the list and will not iterate the list again unless and until it becomes out of date.

Given my specific situation and the above background, what strategy(ies) do you recommend to speed up my app?

**Clarification**

As I wrote in comments below...

For the large query, I'm iterating through all my entities (putting each into a `List<TEntity>`), then doing a giant join, then selecting the actual data I need. For this final selection, some of the data is raw (a basic property of the entity), while some is calculated (a property getter that depends on basic properties of the entity). For the calculated properties, there are sometimes LINQ queries involved. So, a lot of the heavy lifting is done in C# rather than via the database (which is file-based, being SQL CE).

For everything else in my app. I directly query the database when possible and make no attempt to cache anything. If I could figure out a way to completely cache everything that is read-only into memory, I have to believe that would improve performance, but I'm not entirely clear on how to do that given that (1) I have entities that store other entities and (2) the entities have getters, some of which perform queries.

Comment: Have you done the usual SQL query analysis? (As well as a general performance analysis, as "processor intensive" in mentioned.) Just make sure what you are trying to make faster is the part that needs making faster... there really is no point trying to optimize before the problems are well-identified.

Comment: along with @pst question do you have code that's written that you could paste online here where someone may be able to visually point out any pitfalls if you are encountering them

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me from your question, this large query that gets run to output a file, are you iterating through all your entities and running all the little sub queries? or are you passing one monster query to the sql db that returns all the data at once? Also, is there a reason you can't use a [materialized?] view for this specific report?

Comment: @Prescott, you're right. Not clear. For the large query, I'm iterating through all my entities (putting each into a `List<TEntity>`), then doing a giant join, then selecting the actual data I need. For this final selection, some of the data is raw (a basic property of the entity), while some is calculated (a property getter that depends on basic properties of the entity). For the calculated properties, there are sometimes LINQ queries involved. So, a lot of the heavy lifting is done in C# rather than via the database (which is file-based, being SQL CE).

Comment: @Prescott (continued), for everything else in my app. I directly query the database when possible and make no attempt to cache anything. If I could figure out a way to completely cache everything that is read-only into memory, I have to believe that would improve performance, but I'm not entirely clear on how to do that given that (1) I have entities that store other entities and (2) the entities have getters, some of which perform queries.

Comment: @DanM - I guess the first thing I'd be investigating is if you can somehow re-write this C# "query" to SQL - that's probably going to be a big boost (even if you cache all the data in your entities, this will still likely be faster). Secondly - there should be a way to override your loading queries to provide hints to cache the data, rather than re-query, but I have never explored this; maybe someone else can jump in

Comment: @Prescott, your first idea would take a lot of refactoring to implement because I'd be limited to only logic that SQL can handle (and I currently have a lot that SQL cannot handle). I've tried variations where I at least do a "prequery" in SQL that does some of the basic joins, but this turned out to be much slower. I have a theory (unverified) that it's quicker to do things in RAM than SQL when working with a file-based database. Your second idea is much more appealing to me, I hope someone does chime in.

Comment: @DanM - might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx. This talks about a second level cache for ObjectContext - in the comments there is another link for DbContext (article in german, code in um.. code). This looks exactly like what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is your friend:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323290

Comment: The article is talking about ASP.NET. Does it apply to desktop applications?

Comment: ...well, +1 for your advice even though your link was for ASP.NET. Caching just the getters with LINQ queries has already made a pretty significant difference.

Comment: If the sql database is on a different machine, then caching should take place on the server.  That doesn't sound like your situation.  However, you might be able to create Views of complicated queries and access them instead running complicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest performance tuning at the database level; creating relevant indexes if applicable.
I've never had to tune a SQLCE database, so a quick google lookup yielded http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/sql-server-ce/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172984(v=sql.90).aspx.

For the join query (your report view), you can introduce materialized views (if such exist in ce).

Comment: I've added a clarification to my question. Basically, I'm only using the database for a basic initial selection for each entity. After that, I'm relying mostly on C# (i.e., "LINQ to objects") to manipulate the raw data into the form I need for output. So, I don't think performance tuning at the database level would get me very far.